# Django InlineFormset with M2M Field

Tags: django, many-to-many, inline-formset

I found a way to do forms of Models that are connected as Foreignkeys to each other.

I am looking for a formset which will create a dynamic form that has a M2M relationship with each other, so following design:

```
class PrescriptionLine(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    drug = models.ForeignKey(Drug, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    morning = models.FloatField(choices=[(val, val) for val in TABLET_INTAKE_QTY], default=0, blank=True, null=True)
 
class Prescription(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    line_prescription = models.ManyToManyField(PrescriptionLine, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    note = models.TextField(max_length=100, default='')
```

Now I can do something like this:

```
PrescriptionFormset = inlineformset_factory(
    Prescription, PrescriptionLine, form=PrescriptionForm,
    fields=['drug', 'morning'], extra=1, can_delete=True
    )
```

But I can't do that because it says that PrescriptionLine has no ForeignKey to Prescription.

How can this be done? Please help I am struggling with this for many months now. The formset itself is kinda ready if need I can add it here?

Answer (score 0):

So the solution is actually quite simple. I didn't follow it through (meaning Update hasn't been tested yet) so far this works:

```
SinglePrescriptionFormset = modelformset_factory(
    PrescriptionLine, form=PrescriptionLineForm, fields='__all__', extra=1, can_delete=True
    )
```

There is one mistake in the error above please note:

```
    line_prescription = models.ManyToManyField(PrescriptionLine)
```

It works this way no need to change anything else.